# Subversive SVN Connectors does not appear in eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

the Subversive SVN Connectors does not appear after rebooting eclipse Juno IDE after installing svn from the eclipse marketplace.

any ideas?

Because of this issue i cannot assign a svn connector to the svn eclipse plugin so therefore it cannot do any svn features at all.

i am running windows 8 and tried to run eclipse in Admin mode but still no joy. anywhere i can download the connectors manually and if so, where do i install it?

Comment: I think you can install also connectors from Eclipse Marketplace

Comment: I cant find them in the marketplace. they dont seem to be there

Comment: I did find the connectors from the Yoxos marketplace but after i rebooted eclipse, SVN still cannot find a connector

Comment: I accidentally cancelled the dialog when it first showed.  It really is a bad design that can't give you a second chance.

Answer (score 60):

Might help someone...

From [polarion](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php) use [this](http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/) update site.
I installed just

1. subversive SVN Connectors
2. SVNKit 1.7.5.v1 Implementation
3. SVN Team provider connectors source

After this I found in eclipse preferences Team->SVN has the svn kit 1.7.5 selected and everything started to working.

Comment: This is really a solution

Comment: And for Kepler use http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/

Answer (score 51):

Just remove .metadata folder in your workspace directory and restart

then windows -> preference -> team -> svn click. It will appear

Comment: This Helped me using Indigo. I installed subclipse, but initially  cancelled out of the Subversive Connector Discovery dialog. Then could not figure out how to get it back or install connectors

Comment: Worked, but removed all project from work space but just re import the projects.

Comment: Worked in JUNO, simple steps, easy to fix

Comment: This deletes the workspace! All settings will be gone. If it is a new workspace no problem, but other otherwise you will loose all settings and will have to re-import all projects.

Comment: You should warn about the side effects of your solution (maybe put a link to questions about metadata or something)

Comment: Worked in Luna. I really would have liked another intuitive way to open the connectors window.

Comment: Please explicitly mention the eclipse version for which this worked. Doesn't work for my eclipse 4.5 & deletes the workspace.

Comment: Worked for me in NeonJEE. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For me, switching to a fresh workspace fixed the issue. I followed this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/201570/#msg_num_6). The automatic connector discovery tool popped up once I switched to a new workspace.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot add new comments. Just facing same problem. Updating @Saran [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15425331/2711023):

Eclipse **Mars** site is

> http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/5.0/mars-site/

Eclipse **Luna** site is

> http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/luna-site/

Eclipse **Kepler**  site is

> http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/

You can install svn conectors manually from there.

(Remember: Help menu -> Install new software -> paste site url)

Answer (score 3):

Can I suggest the CollabNet Eclipse desktop instead of the Marketplace SVN?

http://desktop-eclipse.open.collab.net/

I've found its installation to be much less painful than any other way of getting SVN into Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Switching workspaces worked.

Also for newer Subversive version`s, the **connectors show** on the:
**windows > preferences > team > svn (in a tab inside this window)**, **instead of** the old **svn > connectors menu**.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close your Eclipse.
2. In your workspace directory, open (*.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.prefs*).
3. Change the option **firstStartup=false** to **firstStartup=true**.
4. Re-open Eclipse again.