# How do I fire up the Subversion Connections Discovery after installing the plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, subversive

I manually installed Eclipse Juno Java EE on my Ubuntu 12.04, inside the `/usr/lib` folder, then proceeded creating a link to the `eclipse` executable under `/usr/bin` and finally successfully started the program.

After installing the Subversive plugin, a prompt asked me to restart Eclipse, that I did since I know it's important to immediately install the connectors. However, with this setup **I didn't get the Subversion Connection Discovery window on startup**, nor any error in the error log view.

Now I have the Subversive plugin correctly installed, but no connector set up, and I seem not to be able to find a way for the Connection Discovery window to show up.

I would like not to use backup solutions (i.e. manually installing connectors from repositories) but solve this issue and get the normal procedure, since this is an installation I'll have to deal with for a while, and I feel this problem is a symptom of something wrong in my setup.

Answer (score 4):

Create a dummy project, use Team -> Share, select SVN. The dialog should come up automatically now.

Alternatively install the connectors without the discovery dialog as described in several other SO question like: [Subversive SVN Connectors does not appear in eclipse juno](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14268003/44089). You have to make sure that the update site matches your version of eclipse.

Comment: Have that problem at the moment, does not work at all. The experience I made is once the dialog is skipped, it does not come again.

Comment: I did not skip the dialog, but it did not show up for me until I created a new project.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my Eclipse (4.5), there is a button "Get Connectors" in the "Connectors" tab, if I visit Window/Preferences/Team/SVN. That button did the trick for me.

Comment: You answer should be at the top.. I don't know why it hasn't been up-voted to the top. It covers all cases (including mines) where none of the other answers did the trick. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: In Neon, I have not this button.

Comment: In Mars too there is no such button.

Comment: No such button in Oxygen :(

Answer (score 1):

You will get the Subversion Connector Discovery from 
Windows- Preference- Team- SVN -Svn Connector - Click on Get Connection Buttion